# Notepad++ creates "Notepad++" folder every time I run it

Tags: notepad++

I'm not sure what happened, but since recently my **Notepad++ v.6.7.7** creates folder `"Notepad++"` in where I start it every time I run it.

I tried to change **Default Directory** in the Preferences but it never remembers this and falls back to "Follow current document"

I even reinstalled it - still the same.

Where do I change this back to normal where it starts to respect settings in `%APPDATA%\Notepad++` folder?

Comment: not really a solution, but could you install notepad++ and select the option DON'T use %appdata% folder

Comment: check preferences->backup -> backup on save (should be none).

Comment: @andrew - didn't work.

Comment: @houssam - it's set to none currently

Comment: uninstall Notepad++ and delete %APPDATA%\Notepad++ (if  exists)  and delete c:\program files\Notepad++ (if exists) then reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks @houssam, that worked. It would be great though to know what the real reason for that behaviour was. Ta!

Comment: you are welcome. you mentioned that "I even reinstalled it - still the same.".. this means that the configuration files still exist somewhere (APPDATA or Program files); by deleting them manually, we guarantee that Notepad++ will be installed with new configuration. I have no answer for the question about why NPP creates a folder "Notepad++", I have npp v 6.7.7 installed, it does not create such folder.you may made some changes to its preferences .

Comment: @user1249170. If you got it working, you should write it as an answer and accept it (so others know what the answer is)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an open [bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/bugs/5180/) that apparently was fixed since. The suggested workaround is:

> Open the Notepad++ settings -> Cloud (the OneDrive is inactive and nothing is selected) and select "No Cloud"

Alternatively, remove the folder `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\cloud`.

The other solutions will work, since they do that too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have no way now to prove that it works since I already fixed this by deleting all the folders as mentioned above. I agree that your solution is elegant and if works it is the best. I up voted your answer too.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the bug. Accepting your answer as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**@houssam** suggestion in the comments worked for me - and I'm posting it as an answer. I believe there's more elegant solution to this problem rather than deleting all the settings and reinstalling software. There has to be a flag somewhere in the settings. If you happen to know this - post it as an answer and I will happily accept it.

**Here's what worked for me:**

> uninstall Notepad++ and delete %APPDATA%\Notepad++ (if exists) and delete c:\program files\Notepad++ (if exists) then reinstall it.

Comment: I think I have found the more direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstallation is not required at all.

1. Close Notepad++.
2. Navigate to

> %APPDATA%\Notepad++
>
> Save **session.xml** file by copying it somewhere else (just to restore your previous session)
>
> Delete content of current **Notepad++** directory.
>
> Run and close Notepad++
>
> Restore **session.xml** file.
>
> Run Notepad++ and use it.

Comment: There might be more data loss in the process.

Comment: I like such useless comments :) Can you explain, why? What kind of data?

Comment: For example:user-defined languages. Certain plugin information, such as information about profiles in NppFtp. There is no well defined "white list" that you can backup.

Comment: That's true, it needs some experimets which data could be removed. However... having uninstallation as the other option, mine is slightly better ;)

Comment: Nah... I'm not sure why uninstallation IS still better than just removing the content of a single directory :> At least you would have the same set of opened files in your editor is it really worse than a clean installation? :>

Comment: Better than reinstallation, worse than just reversing the decision that surfaced this bug in the first place.

Comment: Well, the only think that had to be done is an update to a newer version, that's all.